# Print only if cell value is true

Tags: excel, vba

I have set up a print button to check if a cell has a value before printing, however both message boxes pop up but if I select cancel in the message box the sheet still prints. How can I prevent it printing if I click on cancel.

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPrint_Click()
If Sheets("New").Range("email").Value <> "" 
Cancel = True
MsgBox "Email Address Needs to be Completed", vbInformation
If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub
Application.EnableEvents = True
response = MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel)
If response = vbCanel Then Exit Sub
Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
End If
End Sub
```

Thanks in advance for any help
John Davies

Comment: You made a typo at the bottom, `vbCanel`instead of `vbCancel`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a lot going wrong here in my opinion, here's some notes and a suggested improvement:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPrint_Click()
If Sheets("New").Range("email").Value <> "" '// requires a "Then" keyword
Cancel = True   '// Cancel isn't declared as a variable, why is this here?
MsgBox "Email Address Needs to be Completed", vbInformation
If response = vbCancel Then Exit Sub '// response hasn't been assigned a value yet so will be empty
Application.EnableEvents = True '// No events are fired at this point so not sure why this is here
response = MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel)
If response = vbCanel Then Exit Sub '// typo - should be "vbCancel"
Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True
End If '// End If without valid If block.
End Sub
```

You should also try indenting your statements to make the code easier to read which incidentally helps a lot when it comes to finding and fixing errors. Here's an example of what I believe this code should look like:

```
Private Sub CommandButtonPrint_Click()

    If Sheets("New").Range("email").Value = "" Then MsgBox "Email Address Needs to be Completed", vbInformation

    If MsgBox("Do you really want to print?", vbOKCancel) = vbOK Then Sheets("New").PrintOut copies:=1, Collate:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for that but it still causes a problem.  If the pop up message pops up stating that the email address needs to be completed, I then click on to cancel the print so that I can complete the email address. However once the email field has been completed and I then click on the print button nothing happens.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hi. I'm afraid that the amended code does not really work.  If the email field is blank the pop up message asks if I want to print. However, if there is a value in the "email" range the pop up message states that the email field needs completing (this seems opposite to what is required) but also it does not then give the option to print and just closes down.

Comment: Operator was the wrong way around, I've edited the above. The sub stops because I presume you don't want to quit if the email address isn't complete? Or do you want the user to input the email address and just carry on?

Comment: Thanks very much for that.  I would like the option to carry on and print if the email address is blank, if that is possible.

Comment: Okay in that case you only need two simple 'If' statements, see further edit above.

Comment: Thanks very much for your patience. That works exactly as  I want.

Answer (score 1):

You wrote "vbCanel" instead of "vbCancel". Which of course is never "True" and so you never exit the procedure.